# Как сделать так чтобы пробросилось исключение для пустого списка?

Tags: java

```
public double getBottomBorder() {
    double max = ships.get(0).y + ships.get(0).height;
        for (EnemyShip enemyShip : ships) {
            if (enemyShip.y + enemyShip.height > max)
                max = enemyShip.y + enemyShip.height;
        }
    try {
        return max;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `try` поместите в начало метода, перед тем как читать из списка значение.

Comment: а у самого списка перед тем как дергать у него элементы запросить? if(ships==null || ships.isEmpty()) return 0; исключение работает достаточно быстро. если вы его все равно перехватываете и дальше не бросаете, то может и нет смысла его генерировать и обрабатывать?

Comment: Помещаем всЁ в try и создаем проброс исключениям тем которые произойдут в try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
public double getBottomBorder() {
 try {
 double max = ships.get(0).y + ships.get(0).height;
     for (EnemyShip enemyShip : ships) {
         if (enemyShip.y + enemyShip.height > max)
             max = enemyShip.y + enemyShip.height;
     }

     return max;
 } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
     return 0;
 }
 catch(NullPointerException e) {
     return 0;
 }
}
```

ну или по рекомендациям

```
public double getBottomBorder() {
 try {
  if (ships != null && !ships.isEmpty()) {
     double max = get(0).y + ships.get(0).height;
     for (EnemyShip enemyShip : ships) {
         if (enemyShip.y + enemyShip.height > max)
             max = enemyShip.y + enemyShip.height;
     }    
     return max;
    } else {
      throw new NoSuchElementException(); 
   }  
 } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
     return 0;
 }     
}
```